# How to type a function that converts DOM to a nested array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dom

If we wanted to create a function that given a `body` returns a nested array how would we type it? The problem is that the nested array can be of any depth.

For example, for this markup

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Nodes to Array</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="1">
      <div id="4"></div>
      <div id="5">
        <div id="6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="2"></div>
    <div id="3">
      <div id="7"></div>
      <div id="8"></div>
      <div id="9"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The function would return `["BODY",[["HEADER",[]],["MAIN",[["DIV",[]],["DIV",[]]]],["FOOTER",[]]]]`

```js
// rest of the code omitted

function nodesToArr() {
  const nodesArray = ['BODY', formatNodes(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.body.children))];
  let currentParentNodes = nodesArray[1];

  while (anyChildren(currentParentNodes)) {
    currentParentNodes = getNextGenerationParents(currentParentNodes);
  }

  getNextGenerationParents(currentParentNodes);

  return nodesArray;
}
```

How would be type the return value of this function when we don't know the depth of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Probably like this:

```
type RecursiveArray<T> = (T | RecursiveArray<T>)[];

declare const array: RecursiveArray<string>;

const a = array[0];
//    ^? string | RecursiveArray<string>
```

It'll make working with your return value a lot more annoying, though. Also, you might have to use an assertion or some other workaround when you return a value in your function if you use this as the return type.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W4nRKN)

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, working with the return value is painful now as I can't use `length` since I am getting the error message that `length` property doesn't exist on `RecursiveArray`

Comment: @SrdjaNo1 No, you should still be able to use `length` since strings and arrays have lengths?